# How can I replace last empy row in DataFrame (pandas,python)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, replace

I want export statistics from Oracle to Excel via python, I almost did everything
I have than results:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
1) Use data=pd.read_sql(select slid,name,sum(lines),sum(packs) group by...)
2) sum_row=data[["LINES","PACKS","PACKS_C"]].sum()
3) data_final=data.append(sum_row,ignore_index=True)
```

After that, I got:

[image]

I want to change last row, under column "OT" where empty value, there must be added a word like "Total"
I tried use `data_final2=data_final.append({'OT':'Total'},ignore_index=True)`
but I had :

[image]

Comment: you could use `fillna()` on the column with with the string `total`

Comment: Thank you, result=data_final.fillna(value={'OT':'Total'})

Comment: If you could include your data as text it would make it easier to test, but it should be as simple as `data_final['OT'].fillna(value='Total'. inplace=True)`